# Google Maps geocode: undefined latitude

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

Hitting a page with the follow script displays:

- lat: undefined
- lon: 51.5001524

Why is it that while lat is undefined, lon is not?
A working example can be found [here](http://jordanarsenault.com/testGeoCode.php).

Pull up your web console and see for yourself!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var geocoder;
function codeAddress() 
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = 'London, England';
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) 
    {   
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
      {
        lat = results[0].geometry.location.Ia;
        lon = results[0].geometry.location.Ja;

        console.log("lat: " + lat);
        console.log("lon: " + lon);
      }
    });
}
    codeAddress();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

While we're at it - what is the historical significance of Ia and Ja? I presume it relates to the Cartesian unit vectors i and j (predominately used in Engineering) though I'm not sure.

I found other examples online who use `.lat` for `.Ia` and `.lng` for `.Ja`

These, however, are returning in the console:

```
function () {
    return this[a];
}
```

Just need a kick in the right direction.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `lat()` and `lng()`:

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

Comment: lat(); and lng(); work as opposed to lat; and lng; Thanks. As for Ia and Ja, what is their significance in comparison... anybody?

I'm certain Ia and Ja were working... even a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

This is a designed behaviour of the geocoder: google shifts the identifiers in

```
geometry.location.Ia;
geometry.location.Ja;
```

on a weekly basis, i.e. from above to

```
geometry.location.Ja;
geometry.location.Ka;
```

and so on, so it is not possible to refer by id to the geocoder result object.

Comment: interesting... what is the purpose of making these weekly changes?

Comment: not on a weekly basis, but they APIs are WIP. It's now almost 10/2011 and it is still Ja and Ka. Also there are a lot of parameters to be passed, it could just be that the defaults changed. See here: http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

Comment: currently Ua and Va (for what it's worth) so they are defiantly not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are Google are using a javascript minifier (e.g. http://jscompress.com/) which renames all variables - hence they're subject to change on every build.